# Unable to use InitializeDatabaseConnection() in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Whenever I try to run WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(), it fails with the error

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not
>   be installed.

Here is the method call:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DataContext", "Users", "Id", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

Here's my database connection string (which I use in the MVC application and works fine):

```
<add name="DataContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.DataModel.csdl|res://*/Entities.DataModel.ssdl|res://*/Entities.DataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

And here's my :

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      <add name="SqlClient Data Provider"
       invariant="System.Data.SqlClient"
       description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer"
       type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, System.Data,
     Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Here's the callback:

> [ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data
>   Provider.  It may not be installed.]
>   System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String
>   providerInvariantName) +1426271
>   WebMatrix.Data.DbProviderFactoryWrapper.CreateConnection(String
>   connectionString) +64
>   WebMatrix.Data.<>c_*DisplayClass15.b*_14()
>   +16    WebMatrix.Data.Database.get_Connection() +19    WebMatrix.Data.Database.EnsureConnectionOpen() +12
>   WebMatrix.Data.d__0.MoveNext() +66
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +164
>   WebMatrix.Data.Database.QuerySingle(String commandText, Object[] args)
>   +103    WebMatrix.WebData.DatabaseWrapper.QuerySingle(String commandText, Object[] parameters) +14
>   WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CheckTableExists(IDatabase
>   db, String tableName) +57
>   WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateTablesIfNeeded() +49 
>   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeMembershipProvider(SimpleMembershipProvider
>   simpleMembership, DatabaseConnectionInfo connect, String
>   userTableName, String userIdColumn, String userNameColumn, Boolean
>   createTables) +73
>   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeProviders(DatabaseConnectionInfo
>   connect, String userTableName, String userIdColumn, String
>   userNameColumn, Boolean autoCreateTables) +51
>   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(String
>   connectionStringName, String userTableName, String userIdColumn,
>   String userNameColumn, Boolean autoCreateTables) +51
>   UPI.Web.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in
>   c:\Users\danderson\Documents\UnitedPiping\LEMTracking\trunk\Source\Web\Global.asax.cs:36
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to find the requested .Net
>   Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +9860225
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +336
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +296
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to find the requested .Net
>   Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9874568 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254

**EDIT:**

After following allo_man's instructions (sorta--that exact code didn't work so I looked up the class on MSDN and used their example), I'm getting a new error. "Illegal characters in path."

```
  // Specify the provider name, server and database. 
  string providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient";
  string serverName = "(LocalDB)\v11.0";
  string databaseName = "aoeu";

  // Initialize the connection string builder for the 
  // underlying provider.
  SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

  // Set the properties for the data source.
  sqlBuilder.DataSource = serverName;
  sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = databaseName;
  sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;

  // Build the SqlConnection connection string. 
  string providerString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

  // Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder.
  EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder =
      new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

  //Set the provider name.
  entityBuilder.Provider = providerName;

  // Set the provider-specific connection string.
  entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerString;

  // Set the Metadata location.
  entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/Entities.DataModel.csdl|
                    res://*/Entities.DataModel.ssdl|
                    res://*/Entities.DataModel.msl";

  //var builder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
  //string sqlConnString = builder.ConnectionString;
  WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(entityBuilder.ConnectionString, "Users", "Id", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

Trace:

> [ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.]
>   System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean
>   checkAdditional) +10667574    System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1,
>   String path2) +42
>   WebMatrix.Data.ConfigurationManagerWrapper.GetConnection(String name,
>   Func`2 getConfigConnection, Func`2 fileExists) +208
>   WebMatrix.Data.ConfigurationManagerWrapper.GetConnection(String name)
>   +91    WebMatrix.Data.Database.OpenNamedConnection(String name, IConfigurationManager configurationManager) +18
>   WebMatrix.Data.Database.Open(String name) +61
>   WebMatrix.WebData.DatabaseConnectionInfo.Connect() +149
>   WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.ConnectToDatabase() +56
>   WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateTablesIfNeeded() +67 
>   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeMembershipProvider(SimpleMembershipProvider
>   simpleMembership, DatabaseConnectionInfo connect, String
>   userTableName, String userIdColumn, String userNameColumn, Boolean
>   createTables) +169
>   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeProviders(DatabaseConnectionInfo
>   connect, String userTableName, String userIdColumn, String
>   userNameColumn, Boolean autoCreateTables) +99
>   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(String
>   connectionStringName, String userTableName, String userIdColumn,
>   String userNameColumn, Boolean autoCreateTables) +100
>   UPI.Web.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in
>   c:\Users\danderson\Documents\UnitedPiping\LEMTracking\trunk\Source\Web\Global.asax.cs:73

Comment: Have you installed Sql Server Ce.4.0?

Comment: @Oscar Yes, I have "Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 SP1 x64 ENU" installed.

Comment: Your database is a LocalDB of SQLCE 4.0?

Comment: @allo_man Nope, SQL CE shouldn't even be remotely relevant to this whole thing. I added System.Data.EntityClient to my DbProviderFactories and now I'm getting a different error (still on the same function call): `The parameter name '0' is not valid. A valid parameter name must begin with a letter and contain only letters, numbers, and underscores.` Last function in the callback is `System.Data.EntityClient.EntityParameter.SetParameterNameWithValidation(String parameterName, String argumentName) +8086976` so I guess parameterName was getting a 0? I have no idea where the 0 is coming from...

Comment: Take a look at this anwser. It might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693499/asp-net-system-data-entityclient-connection-string-help

Comment: @allo_man Thanks, but I included my connection string above and it's all as it should be (well, at least based on the link you posted). Still have no idea where the 0 is coming from

Comment: not sure if your code here is an exact replica of what's in your project, but it is important for the `entityBuilder.Metadata` to be one single continuous string with no line breaks or excess spaces.  if you broke it to multiple lines here for readability, ok... but you can't break it in the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an EntityFramework connection with WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection. If you want to have the same connection string you can use the EntityConnectionSTring Builder

```
var builder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(entityConnectionString);
string sqlConnString = builder.ConnectionString;
```

Then initialise SimpleMembershipProvider with that connection string

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(sqlConnString, "User", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000869/can-simplemembership-and-entity-framework-share-a-connection-string)

Comment: Thank you, this helped. However, I'm still getting an error from InitializeDatabaseConnection()--"Illegal characters in path." See my edit on original post for more information.

Comment: Could you post the content of the entityBuilder.ConnectionString from the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions of SQL CE you had to install both version, 32 and 64 bits in order to work.. 
Check in your machine.config file that the SQL CE data provider is registered properly.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Entity doesn't work for this, even using the class allo_man suggested. It works, however, if I add another connection string to Web.config that uses System.Data.SqlClient and then use that with InitializeDatabaseConnection()